# Is there a good way to preload or include a script prior to executing another script?

Tags: bash

I am looking to execute a script but have it include another script before it executes.  The problem is, the included script would be generated and the executed script would be unmodifiable.  One solution I came up with, was to actually reverse the include, by having the include script as a wrapper, calling `set` to set the arguments for the executed script and then dotting/sourcing it.  E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generated wrapper or include script.
: Performing some setup...

target_script=$1 ; shift
set -- "$@"
. "$target_script"
```

Where `target_script` is the script I actually want to run, importing settings from the wrapper.

However, the potential problem I face is that callers of the target script or even the target script itself may be expecting `$0` to be set to the path of it's location on the file system.  But because this wrapper approach overrides `$0`, the value of `$0` may be unexpected and could produce undefined behaviour.

Is there another way to perform what is in effect, an `LD_PRELOAD` but in the scripted form, through bash without interfering with its runtime parameters?

I have looked at `--init-file` or `--rcfile`, but these only seem to be included for interactive shells.

Comment: Hmm...I thought I had a better idea (which is why I removed the comment about `bash -i --init-file`), but it doesn't work out terribly well; the `BASH_*` variables come out odd. `bash -i --init-file` is possibly the least invasive; I don't know many scripts that check whether the shell in which they run is interactive.

Comment: I also tried it and it didn't produce anything too adverse.  See my answer below.  If you would like to answer and I will delete my own answer, since it was inspired by your suggestion anyway...

Comment: Nah, that's alright. No need to squabble over internet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the bash documentation:

```
When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable  BASH_ENV  in
the  environment,  expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read
and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
       if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.
```

So that settles it then:

```
BASH_ENV=/tmp/x-include.sh /bin/bash /tmp/xx.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Forcing interactive mode does seem to allow me to specify `--rcfile`:

```
$ bash --rcfile /tmp/x-include.sh -i /tmp/xx.sh
include_script: $0=bash, $BASH_SOURCE=/tmp/x-include.sh
target_script: $0=/tmp/xx.sh, $BASH_SOURCE=/tmp/xx.sh
```

Content of the `x-include.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "include_script: \$0=$0, \$BASH_SOURCE=$BASH_SOURCE"
```

Content of the `xx.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "target_script: \$0=$0, \$BASH_SOURCE=$BASH_SOURCE"
```